# sendOrderedBroadcast - which thread is response receiver run?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-broadcastreceiver

If I do:

```
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", "OK");
        } else {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "Fail!");
        }
    }
}, null, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null, null);
```

On which thread is the `onReceive()` method run? On the sending thread or on the UI thread?

Comment: from the docs: `scheduler` A custom Handler with which to schedule the resultReceiver callback; if null it will be scheduled in the Context's main thread

Comment: So that means on the ui thread, right?

Comment: just use `Log.d` and `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: That yields that it is the same as the UI thread. Great!

Answer (score 0):

OnReceive is always invoked on the UI thread of the application in which Receiver is registered.

In this case UI / Main thread of the same application.